# Adding additional water to already simmering bone stock

Tags: stock

I am making stock from bones and I was simmering it with the lid off. I want to simmer it for 3 days. This morning the liquid was reduced by a significant amount even though the heat was extremely low. I put the lid on to stop the evaporation but is it okay to add new water to the stock? Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to simmer for three days?

Comment: This is why pressure cookers were invented.

Answer (score 7):

I have never seen a stock recipe that recommended 3 days. In my experience, after 12 hours the bones gave up all they had and would crumble when touched.

Even so- simmering with the lid off will cause quite a bit of evaporation. Definitely add water whenever you notice it is low.

I've had stocks dry up completely and it smells absolutely horrible when they burn.

Comment: ...and good luck cleaning the pot afterward.

Comment: It's easy to clean a pot like that, just toss it in the trash ><